# PHP, mysql - get error on result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is my PHP code:

```
$conn = openConnection();

$uuid_device = isset($_REQUEST['uuid_device']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['uuid_device']) : "NoValueSet";
$email = isset($_REQUEST['email']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['email']) : "NoValueSet";

$randomString = generateRandomString();

// got unrelevent code here in the middle

$query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users "
        . "SET user_code= ? "
        . "WHERE email = ? and uuid_device = ? ");// or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$query->bind_param("sss", $randomString, $email, $uuid_device);

$query->execute();// or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$result = $query->fetch();
if(!$result){
    // failed inserting to DB
    statusFailed('query failed');
}
```

I get my json with the "query failed" string, which means my result is not good for some reason.

I check that my variables `$uuid_device`, `$email` and `$randomString` aren't `null` before using them.

I dont know if my mysql statement is the problem or maybe something else. I've tried looking for similar problems in google but found nothing.

Comment: There's a function called `mysqli_error()`, why not use that? What's the output of `if (!$query->error) {
   printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $query->error);
}`?

Comment: Yea, gave it. Check?

Comment: Errormessage: {"status":"ERROR","data":"query failed","time":"13:50:21, 30.06.2016"}

Comment: This is what i get. I get the same json with the same reason 'query failed'

Comment: You didn't use the code I provided. Or you need to be doing it some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = $query->execute();// or die(mysqli_error($conn));
if(!$result){
    // failed inserting to DB
    statusFailed('query failed');
}
```

You don't have to fetch to get if query went through. There's nothing to fetch after update, so just trust the return of execute()